# Invoices with Pay Now button Android

Tags: java, android, paypal, platform, invoice

I am building an application where I want my users to be able to invoice their customers. I also want them to be able to accept PayPal/credit cards through a “pay now” button on each invoice their customers receive. I understand PayPal has an invoicing system in which my application could have Paypal send invoices to my user’s customers on my user’s behalf, however I would like to build the invoices within my application to keep control of the templates/design and provide traditional invoicing for users who do not want to accept cards.

Is there a way to utilize a pay now button within a custom created invoice? if so, what is the best route?

Comment: doesn't paypal has an api rather than a  invoice template? the api will probably give you methods to use to accept a credit card. you need to think about security though.

Comment: Yes they do, I ended up going this route. Thanks for your input.